# How to access model data in parent partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one controller which will pass data to view Index.cshtml

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var empId = @User.Identity.Name;
        var empDetails = empRepository.GetEmployeeDetails(empId);
        var emp = new UserViewModel {EmployeeDetail = empDetails};
        return View(emp);
    }
```

Layout of view Index.cshtml is Partialview _Layout.cshtml

```
@model HRM.Areas.EmployeeDetails.Models.UserViewModel
@{
       ViewBag.Title = "Index";
       Layout = "~/Areas/EmployeeDetails/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

 <div>Hello</div>
```

I want to access the data which I passed from controller action to Index.cshtml in _Layout.cshtml.

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear on how you want to access the values so i'm making an assumption here:

If you want to include data from a view in a rendering from your `layout` page you can use the RenderSection method.

Layout Page:

```
@RenderSection("ViewSection", false)
```

View Page:

```
@section ViewSection {
<div>
    <label>Emp Name:</label>
    @model.EmpDetails.Name    
</div>

}
```

When your `Layout` is rendered it'll look for a section in your view that matches and render it.  Passing a false as the 2nd param tell the Layout that the section is not required.

For more info on this:  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx

Comment: I have other views who has _Layout.cshtml as its parent view.If I do this way then I have to make section in each view.

Comment: Yeah, my example was not great.  I've edited it.  If your other views don't define a section called `ViewSection` then the parent layout page will just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear to me:/

My assumption -> 
If you change your code to look like this:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var empId = @User.Identity.Name;
            var empDetails = empRepository.GetEmployeeDetails(empId);
            var emp = new UserViewModel { EmployeeDetail = empDetails };

            ViewBag.UserViewModel = emp;

            return View(emp);
        }
```

on the Layout page you can access your data:

```
@if (ViewBag.UserViewModel != null)
{
    //do sth with ViewBag.UserViewModel here
    //for example:
    @Html.Partial("_UserView",ViewBag.UserViewModel)

}
```

If you explain in details what you want to achive it will be easier for us to give you the right answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can access the data in the model like this:

@Model.EmployeeDetail ...